# How to identify largest bounding rectangles from an image and separate them into separate images using Opencv and python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am new to Opencv and python and trying to identify the largest three rectangles as marked in the [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq1aF.jpg) and extract them into three separate images. I am able to identify contours in the image but all of them are showing up (as shown in [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrVdq.png)) and I am not able to separate out the three largest ones.
Code I have written so far:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('imgpath')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 130, 255, 1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

#largest_contours = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-3:]
#print(len(largest_contours))
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (0,255,0), 3)

#cv2.imshow("result", image)
#cv2.drawContours(image, largest_contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Could you add your original input image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Adaptive threshold to get a binary image
- Find contours and sort for largest three
- Perform contour approximation to ensure we have a square contour
- Perform perspective transform to get top-down view
- Rotate image to get correct orientation

---

The extracted rectangles after performing perspective transform and rotating

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    # Grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # Compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    def order_corner_points(corners):
        # Separate corners into individual points
        # Index 0 - top-right
        #       1 - top-left
        #       2 - bottom-left
        #       3 - bottom-right
        corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
        top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
        return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:3]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 3)
        transformed = perspective_transform(original, approx)
        rotated = rotate_image(transformed, -90)
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), rotated)
        cv2.imshow('ROI_{}'.format(ROI_number), rotated)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This is perfect nathancy. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: though it is off topic, but do you know a way in which I can also extract text for each label from this image ? If I use tesseract or google vision api, they just extract plain text without giving meaningful information on which label it corresponds to. Any guidance for this problem shall be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the contours according to their area and then pick the top three.

```
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda c: cv2.contourArea(c), reverse=True)
    for c in cnts[:3]:
        cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
```

(x,y,w,h) represent co-ordinates (x,y), width and height of the contour. These values can be used to crop out the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code but it only gets me top rectangle and some portions of second and third rectangle. It does not even get boundary of second and third one.
#largest_contours = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-3:]
My commented code also gave me the same result. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Check out how it displays after sorting and picking top three: https://imgur.com/a/y8FmNC8

Comment: instead of draw Contours, use
    `(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)`
    `cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)`

Comment: Tried boundingRect instead of draw contours. Still not getting result. Please refer to: https://imgur.com/a/ouGTJnB